# Strange issue on window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a rather strange problem when using `window.print()`.
I have a page which needs to have a different print layout than what's normally shown to the user. Thus I've created an overlay which is shown when the user clicks the `print` button and then it triggers `window.print()`. Everything works just fine, except for some unknown reason the print window shows more than once. If I click the print button for the first time I get the print windows 2 times, the second time I get it 4 times.

HTML:

```
<div id="printDiv" style="position: fixed; overflow: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: white; z-index: 9999;display: none;">
   The print page content
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function show_print(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast', function () {
        window.print();
    });
}
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Could you use media queries instead of javascript?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Media queries is close but not right. The `@media`-rule is what he should use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: I tested this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wBSBu/3/ and it prints twice, if I change to just one selector `$('html')`, it'll only print once. http://jsfiddle.net/ThFvD/, as I suppose animate is binding itself to animate each property in the object, thus iterating twice. But I'm not entirely sure this is the answer =)

Comment: @MackieeE you are absolutely right! I haven't seen this was selecting two elements and thus was being fired twice. Could you please submit your answer so I could accept it? :)

Comment: Sure thing! Glad was able to help =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it may be because you're selecting [two elements](http://jsfiddle.net/wBSBu/3) thus firing twice as it iterates on each element found within the jQuery selector.

Thus, by adjusting it to `$('html')` tag only:

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast', 'swing', function () {
    window.print(); //Prints once
});
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ThFvD/